# Why does the strwrap function in R change some characters to some sort of byte sequence?

Tags: r, linux

```
> s <- " ‘in silico’’) and the object o"
> strwrap(s, 5)
[1] "<e2><80><98>in"                  "silico<e2><80><99><e2><80><99>)"
[3] "and"                             "the"
[5] "object"                          "o"
```

Some characters are changed to those weird angle bracket byte sequences by the `strwrap()` function in base R. Is there a way I could to convert these sequences in the wrapped string back to the original characters? Why would the function do this in the first place? Using `stringi::stri_wrap()`, the problem can be nicely avoided.

Just in case this has to do with locale settings here is my session info

```
R version 4.2.0 (2022-04-22)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: Ubuntu 20.04 LTS

Matrix products: default
BLAS:   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/openblas-pthread/libblas.so.3
LAPACK: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/openblas-pthread/liblapack.so.3

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C
 [3] LC_TIME=es_ES.UTF-8        LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF-8
 [5] LC_MONETARY=es_ES.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8
 [7] LC_PAPER=es_ES.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C
 [9] LC_ADDRESS=C               LC_TELEPHONE=C
[11] LC_MEASUREMENT=es_ES.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C

attached base packages:
[1] grid      stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods
[8] base

other attached packages:
[1] stringi_1.7.6     gridExtra_2.3     data.table_1.14.2

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] compiler_4.2.0 magrittr_2.0.3 tools_4.2.0    gtable_0.3.0   stringr_1.4.0
```

Comment: It’s obviously butchering multi-byte UTF-8 characters such as `’` by tearing the constituent bytes apart and “interpreting” them as separate old ASCII bytes. No clue why; Unicode support doesn’t look all that bad in R altogether…

Comment: Also of note: I can't reproduce on my R 4.3.2 on Windows (locale `English_United States.utf8`). What is the result of `Encoding(s)`?

Comment: Good point. I have R 4.3.2 on ArchLinux. Also can’t reproduce it. Multibyte characters look OK. My locale is `cs_CZ.UTF-8`. Well, almost, because apparently R has a different understanding of locale (more vars). `Sys.getlocale()` says: `"LC_CTYPE=cs_CZ.UTF-8;LC_NUMERIC=C;LC_TIME=cs_CZ.UTF-8;LC_COLLATE=cs_CZ.UTF-8;LC_MONETARY=cs_CZ.UTF-8;LC_MESSAGES=cs_CZ.UTF-8;LC_PAPER=cs_CZ.UTF-8;LC_NAME=C;LC_ADDRESS=C;LC_TELEPHONE=C;LC_MEASUREMENT=cs_CZ.UTF-8;LC_IDENTIFICATION=C"`

Comment: Can confirm no problem getting it "right" under MacOS, R 4.3.1

Comment: Returns `"‘in"       "silico’’)" "and"       "the"       "object"    "o" ` using R 4.2.3, locale `English_New Zealand.utf8`.

Comment: Can't reproduce, Linux, en_US.UTF-8, R 4.3.2

Comment: Works on my machine (en_US locale) and on Fedora.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure about your `sessionInfo`? I can reproduce this somewhat, setting locale all to "C". Setting `Sys.setlocale("LC_ALL", "en_US.UTF-8")` helped. Do you have locale specific entries in your `.Renviron`, `Renviron`,  `Renviron.site`, `Rprofile.site`?

```
> s <- " ‘in silico’’) and the object o"
> Sys.setlocale("LC_ALL", "C")
[1] "LC_CTYPE=C;LC_NUMERIC=C;LC_TIME=C;LC_COLLATE=C;LC_MONETARY=C;LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8;LC_PAPER=C;LC_NAME=C;LC_ADDRESS=C;LC_TELEPHONE=C;LC_MEASUREMENT=C;LC_IDENTIFICATION=C"
> strwrap(s, 5)
[1] "<U+2018>in"          "silico<U+2019><U+2019>)" "and"                 "the"                
[5] "object"              "o"                  
> stringi::stri_wrap(s, 5)
[1] "<U+2018>in"          "silico<U+2019><U+2019>)" "and"                 "the"                
[5] "object"              "o"                  
> Sys.setlocale("LC_ALL", "en_US.UTF-8")
[1] "LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8;LC_NUMERIC=C;LC_TIME=en_US.UTF-8;LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF-8;LC_MONETARY=en_US.UTF-8;LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8;LC_PAPER=C;LC_NAME=C;LC_ADDRESS=C;LC_TELEPHONE=C;LC_MEASUREMENT=C;LC_IDENTIFICATION=C"
> strwrap(s, 5)
[1] "‘in"       "silico’’)" "and"       "the"       "object"    "o"        
> stringi::stri_wrap(s, 5)
[1] "‘in"       "silico’’)" "and"       "the"       "object"    "o"        
> sessionInfo()
R version 4.3.2 (2023-10-31)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS

Matrix products: default
BLAS:   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/blas/libblas.so.3.10.0 
LAPACK: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/lapack/liblapack.so.3.10.0

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8    LC_NUMERIC=C            LC_TIME=en_US.UTF-8    
 [4] LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF-8  LC_MONETARY=en_US.UTF-8 LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8
 [7] LC_PAPER=C              LC_NAME=C               LC_ADDRESS=C           
[10] LC_TELEPHONE=C          LC_MEASUREMENT=C        LC_IDENTIFICATION=C    

time zone: Europe/Zurich
tzcode source: system (glibc)

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] compiler_4.3.2 tools_4.3.2    stringi_1.8.3
```